# Value Count combing two columns

Tags: python, sorting, pandas-groupby, seaborn

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
dfexcel= pd.read_excel('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArsenioMGonzalez3/Project3_ABDS/master/Open%20Parking%20and%20Camera%20Violations_OH%20NY_2019_2020%20YTD.xlsx')
dfexcel = dfexcel[['Issuing Agency','State']].sort_values(by = 'Issuing Agency' ,  ascending=False)
dfexcel
```

this code generates all the violations issued by each different agency for vechicles registered to either NY or OH.

how can I see how many violation each agency issued for both NY/OH

for example: Traffic agency issused 42 for NY and 2 for OH

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby then get the size of each group:

```
dfexcel.groupby(['State','Issuing Agency']).size()
```

Output:

```
State  Issuing Agency
NY     CON RAIL                                  2
       DEPARTMENT OF SANITATION               2457
       DEPARTMENT OF TRANSPORTATION          22065
       FIRE DEPARTMENT                           8
       HOUSING AUTHORITY                         2
       NYC TRANSIT AUTHORITY MANAGERS            6
       NYS OFFICE OF MENTAL HEALTH POLICE        2
       OTHER/UNKNOWN AGENCIES                  239
       PARKS DEPARTMENT                         54
       POLICE DEPARTMENT                     10340
       PORT AUTHORITY                            5
       TRAFFIC                               26344
OH     DEPARTMENT OF SANITATION                  7
       DEPARTMENT OF TRANSPORTATION             47
       PARKS DEPARTMENT                          1
       POLICE DEPARTMENT                        13
       TRAFFIC                                  35
```